# Mariadb SQL Select count with group by and select values not null from another

Tags: group-by, count, mariadb

I've a problem to realize my query maybe someone of you can help me :)

I have 3 tables :

1) Documents

```
DocRef  CustRef
Doc1    Cust1
Doc2    Cust2
Doc3    Cust1
```

2) LinkInter

```
DocRef  InterRef
Doc1    Inter1
Doc2    Inter2
Doc3    Inter3
```

3) Inter

```
id  InterRef    deliverychannel email   mobilenb    date    status
1   Inter1      Email           email1@email.be     2013-01-14T00:00:00Z    ok
2   Inter1      SMS                     0444111111  2013-01-12T00:00:00Z    ko
3   Inter1      Other           email5@email.be     2013-02-21T00:00:00Z    ko
4   Inter2      Email   email2@email.be 044456465465    2013-01-21T00:00:00Z    ko
5   Inter3      Email                               2013-01-21T00:00:00Z    ko
6   Inter3      SMS                                 2013-01-22T00:00:00Z    ko
7   Inter3      Other   email3@mail.be              2013-01-22T00:00:00Z    ko
```

to have a best view go here: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16649f/1)

The result that I want is the following:

```
CustRef | number of InterRef SMS KO| Last email known| Last mobilenb known
Cust1   | 2                        | email5@email.be | 0444111111
```

I want to have all the Customers where the deliverychannel = 'SMS' and the status = 'ko', the number of Inter (Interactions) with the status 'KO', the last email known and the last mobile number known.

I've tried with 2 functions getLastEmailKnown & getLastmobilenbKnown but with my tables that count more than 10.000.000 of records it takes a lot of times

I can have this result with php page but it's not the solution, I want to have  only one query

If I execute 3 queries sepately, it works but i want only one

```
SELECT d.CustRef, count(DISTINCT i.InterRef) , i.email, i.mobilenb
FROM Documents d
    INNER join LinkInter link on link.DocRef = d.DocRef
    INNER join Inter i on i.InterRef = link.InterRef 
          and i.deliverychannel = 'SMS' 
          and i.status = 'ko'
group by d.CustRef 
Order by d.CustRef DESC;

SELECT distinct i.email as lastEmailKnown, d.CustRef
FROM Inter i
    INNER join LinkInter link on link.InterRef = i.InterRef
    INNER join Documents d on d.DocRef = link.DocRef
where d.CustRef = 'Cust1' AND email is not NULL and email <> '' ORDER by date DESC LIMIT 1;

SELECT distinct i.mobilenb as lastmobileKnown, d.CustRef
FROM Inter i
    INNER join LinkInter link on link.InterRef = i.InterRef
    INNER join Documents d on d.DocRef = link.DocRef
where d.CustRef = 'Cust1' AND mobilenb is not NULL and mobilenb <> '' ORDER by date DESC LIMIT 1;
```